# Using a basic fade-in animation when Visibility of a UIElement is changed to "Visible" causes screen to flicker momentarily

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, storyboard

I'm having a frustrating problem running a simple fade in animation in my app.

My app consists of three pivots.

Each pivot contains three sections that have their detailed information "Collapsed" by default and that becomes "Visible" if you tap anywhere on the section.

When you tap to expand the detailed information for a section, a fadeIn() animation is called from the code-behind:

```
nowExpandableContent.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            Storyboard s = new Storyboard();

            DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            fadeInAnimation.From = 0.0;
            fadeInAnimation.To = 1.0;
            fadeInAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

            Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeInAnimation, this.nowExpandableContent);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));

            s.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);

            s.Begin();
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes when I tap a section to expand, the app will flicker/flash momentarily (having paid close attention, I noticed it's showing the content of the other pivots). Sometimes this can happen on my first tap of a section. Other times it can take a few or more taps (open/close/open/close etc.) for it to occur. It's really random.

This is an excerpt from the xaml of the first pivot/section within it (note: the Tap event handler, "Now_Tap", is where the fadeIn method is called from):

```
<controls:PivotItem 
    x:Name="pivotNow"
    Margin="0">

    <ScrollViewer 
        Height="780"
        ManipulationStarted="ScrollViewerToday_ManipulationStarted"
        x:Name="scrollViewerNowPivot">

        <Grid 
            x:Name="GridNow">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!-- NOW -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- NOW ROW START -->
            <StackPanel 
                Background="{Binding ActiveTheme.BackgroundAlt1, Source={StaticResource ThemeController}}"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Tap="Now_Tap">

                <!-- NOW GRID START -->
                <Grid
                    Margin="0,50,0,50">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- NOW TITLE ROW START -->
                    <wptoolkit:WrapPanel 
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!-- NOW TITLE -->
                        <TextBlock 
                            FontSize="18"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Foreground="{Binding ActiveTheme.ForegroundAlt1, Source={StaticResource ThemeController}}"
                            Text="NOW"/>
                        <!-- NOW EXPANDABLE ICON -->
                        <Border 
                            Background="{Binding ActiveTheme.BackgroundAlt1, Source={StaticResource ThemeController}}"
                            BorderBrush="{Binding ActiveTheme.ForegroundAlt1, Source={StaticResource ThemeController}}"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="250"
                            Margin="15,2,0,0"
                            Opacity="0.5"
                            Padding="4,5,4,4"
                            Width="24">
                            <TextBlock 
                                FontSize="10"
                                FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"                                                        
                                Foreground="{Binding ActiveTheme.ForegroundAlt1, Source={StaticResource ThemeController}}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Opacity="0.5"
                                Text="&#xE109;"                                            
                                x:Name="nowExpandableIcon"/>
                        </Border>
                    </wptoolkit:WrapPanel>
                    <!-- NOW TITLE ROW END -->

                    <!-- NOW CONTENT ROW START -->
                    <StackPanel 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,50,0,50">
                        <wptoolkit:WrapPanel>
                            <!-- NOW ICON -->
                            <TextBlock 
                                FontSize="80" 
                                FontWeight="Bold" 
                                FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/WeatherIcons-Regular.otf#Weather Icons"
                                Foreground="{Binding PivotNow.IconColour}" 
                                Text="{Binding PivotNow.Icon}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            <!-- NOW TEMPERATURE -->
                            <TextBlock 
                                FontSize="90"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Margin="40,0,0,-5"
                                Text="{Binding Location.Currently.Temperature}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </wptoolkit:WrapPanel>
                        <!-- NOW SUMMARY -->
                        <TextBlock 
                            FontSize="24"
                            Margin="0,20,0,0"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                <Run Text="{Binding PivotNow.Summary}"/><Run Text="."/> <Run Text="Feels like "/><Run Text="{Binding Location.Currently.ApparentTemperature}"/><Run Text="."/>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <!-- NOW EXPANDABLE CONTENT -->
                        <TextBlock        
                            FontSize="24"
                            Margin="0,30,0,0"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Text="{Binding Location.Currently.ExpandableContent}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            x:Name="nowExpandableContent"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!-- NOW CONTENT ROW END -->

                </Grid>
                <!-- NOW GRID END -->
            </StackPanel>
            <!-- NOW ROW END -->
```

I know it's tough to diagnose the root cause of this issue without having access to the entire xaml/debugging application, but are there any hints towards what may be causing this behaviour from what I have shared? If not, is the general problem I'm having remotely familiar to anyone by any chance?

I should add that this problem never occurs if I expand a section without using an animation.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Opacity` to `0` before call an animation. For now, you make yor element `Visible` and few ticks later begins an animation. This may cause flickering you see

```
nowExpandableContent.Opacity = 0.0;
nowExpandableContent.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Another approach if this doesn't work:

Make all hidden (non-selected) pivot items `Collapsed` by hand, i.e. subscribe to pivot `SelectionChanged` event and make panel which is navigated to `Visible` and other pages - `Collapsed`

Comment: That made a lot of sense, and I was sure could be it. But unfortunately not. Still seeing the same problem I'm afraid.

Comment: Recently had such problem, solved by making all hidden pivot items `Collapsed` by hand. Also, `CacheMode` on different pivot items have impact on that flickering

Comment: What do you mean about the CacheMode? Should I or shouldn't I be using it?

Comment: try to add `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` on page where animation happens or on other pages

Comment: Having the non-selected pivots set to "Collapsed" seems to have done the trick! Thanks very much.